# powershell and regex

Tags: regex, powershell

any ideas??

I have this code in hundreds of pages I need to remove it from all these pages but because of the " var s " where everypage is a different 4 digit number i cant just do a find and replace replace with nothing
.
How can I create a powershell command using regex on those four digits.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
var d = '<%=joindomain%>';
var s = '9244';
var a = '<%=Request.QueryString("aff") %>';
var c = '<%=Request.QueryString("camp") %>';
var r = '<%=referer %>';
</script>
```

Thank you
Rico

Comment: Do you mean you need to remove those 7 lines from every file?  Or do you mean that you just need to remove the one line with the 4 digits?

Comment: I need to remove those 7 lines from every file.

Comment: You actually can find/replace even though it's a different 4-digit number. In Powershell regex, `\d` represents any digit, so `\d\d\d\d` would match any 4-digit number.

Comment: I try running this  but I get errors

Comment: $old = '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
 var d = '<%=joindomain%>';
 var s = '\d\d\d\d';
 var a = '<%=Request.QueryString("aff") %>';
 var c = '<%=Request.QueryString("camp") %>';
 var r = '<%=referer %>';
 </script>'

$new = ''

Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\domain_3 -Recurse | Where {$_ -IS [IO.FileInfo]} |

% {

(Get-Content $_.FullName) -replace $old,$new | Set-Content $_.FullName

Write-Host "Processed: " + $_.FullName

}

Comment: Please update your actual question with the new code that you tried instead of trying to squeeze it into a comment.

Comment: And edit your post to include the exact text of the error message (within reason). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how general you can be here... Code below may do more than you ask for, if that is the case - just add more things to disambiguate it. Anyway, it did the job for me... ;)

```
@'
foo
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
var d = '<%=joindomain%>';
var s = '9244';
var a = '<%=Request.QueryString("aff") %>';
var c = '<%=Request.QueryString("camp") %>';
var r = '<%=referer %>';
</script>
bar
'@ -replace '<script language[\s\S]*?var s = ''\d{4}''[\s\S]*?</script>'
```

it will remove any piece of text between "" that contains string "var s = '####'" (4 digits). Notice that I would have to escape things for regex and single quotes for it to work. At some point you may consider [Regex]::Escape method handy, if you want to be very specific...